# Eclipse wont generate R file after ADT 22 Update

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I recently updated to ADT 22.0.5 and now my projects wont generate the R file. I have followed all steps posted in other questions and still have no luck. Any suggestions? I have lost way to much time on this.

[image: SDK Manager]

[image]

[image]

Comment: do you have any errors in your resource files? try clean and build

Comment: I do not, even newly created projects have errors

Answer (score 1):

Check this ,

I had the problem too. There is a new component in the Tools folder called "Android SDK Build-tools" that needs to be installed.

- **Step 1**

  Open the Android SDK Manager
- **Step 2**

  Select the newly added Build Tools and install. (If problem stays then go to Project Properties => Java Build Path => Order and Export and check Android Private Libraries, then clean and build project.

It may be necessary to repeat the process, restart the SDK Manager after the update.